# Easymock with @TestSubject enhanced with CGLIB

Tags: easymock, cglib

Is there a way to  make EasyMock's `@TestSubject` annottation to work when the test subject object is enhanced with CGLIB?

Scenario: the `@TestSubject` object is a Spring bean which was enhanced with CGLIB in order to apply some aspect (assuming that for some reason Spring couldn't use JDK-based proxy). In this case, simply using `@TestSubject` and `EasyMockSupport.injectMocks(this)` does not really work. EasyMock injects the mock, however during execution the mock is not actually used due to how the internals of a CGLIB enhanced class work. In the end it is used the original reference the object had, not the mock.

The only approach I know is to create a setter in the test subject, and to inject the mock manually calling the setter. However sometimes I do not have access/permission/time to change the subject code to include the setter.

Answer (score 0):

cglib classes are always `final` what prevents the creation of another proxy. This is therefore not possible to do. Rather, you would need to discover that a class is a cglib proxy already and rather enhance its base class.